# j2ee injected connection not transaction managed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, cdi, wildfly-10

I'm using CDI to inject Connection in my DAO classes.

The connection producer is like this:

```
public class ConnectionManager {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ConnectionManager.class.getName());

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/PostgresXADS")
    private DataSource flamingoDs;

    @Named("flamingoConnection")
    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public Connection createFlamingoConnection() {
        LOGGER.info("createFlamingoConnection called");
        try {
            return flamingoDs.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    public void closeConnection(@Disposes Connection c) {
        LOGGER.info("closeConnection called");
        try {
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
 }
```

Then in my DAO class for example I have :

```
public class GraphDao {

@Inject
@Named("flamingoConnection")
Connection con;

public String createObjNode(String tipoCod, String nome, Object flmNodeData)
        throws JsonProcessingException, SQLException, IllegalArgumentException {
    if (tipoCod == null || flmNodeData == null || nome == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty parameters");
    }
    LOGGER.info("createObjNode start");
    String generatedUuid;
    String sql = "INSERT INTO graphdb.nodo_oggetto (tipo_cod, nome, dati) VALUES(?, ? ,?) RETURNING  uuid";
    PGobject jsonObject = getJsonPgObj(flmNodeData);
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = this.con.prepareStatement(sql);) {
        stmt.setObject(1, tipoCod);
        stmt.setString(2, nome);
        stmt.setObject(3, jsonObject);
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            rs.next();
            generatedUuid = rs.getString(1);
        }
    }
    LOGGER.info("createObjNode end");
    return generatedUuid;
}
```

I'm calling the dao method inside an ejb method with container managed transaction .

The connection get injected and get closed correctly in the scope of the current thread, but after any query get executed it's immediately committed on the DB.

The Data source i'm using is of type XA it's definition is :

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/PostgresXADS" pool-name="PostgresXADS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
    <xa-datasource-property name="url">
        jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/infostud?ApplicationName=NewSegr
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <driver>postgres</driver>
    <xa-pool>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
        <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
        <no-tx-separate-pools>true</no-tx-separate-pools>
        <wrap-xa-resource>true</wrap-xa-resource>
    </xa-pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>XXX</user-name>
        <password>XXX</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
</xa-datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="postgres" module="org.postgresql">
        <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        <datasource-class>org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource</datasource-class>
</driver>
```

I'm unsing postgresql and WildFly 10

Can someone please explain me why it's happening?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you provide an example where you call this `createObjNode()` and it commits to the database immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have access to the Connection instance, could you try to set the auto-commit to false?

```
Connection conn = flamingoDs.getConnection();  
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
return conn;
```

According to the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit(boolean)), it is set to true by default.

By the way, I think you should not produce the connection in a CDI producer, but rather create it in the try-with-resources:

```
 try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql))
```